# Is $f(t) = e^{X(t)}$ continuous when matrix $X(t)$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, continuity, matrix-exponential

I think $f(t) = e^{X(t)}$ is continuous over $t \in \mathbb{R}$ when the complex matrix valued mapping $t\mapsto X(t)$ is continuous - regardless of whether $X$ is infinite or finite dimension. I tried to think of a proof, but without much success.

The hard part is the infinite-dimensional case, and I do not know what a proof could look like.

Comment: The composed of two continuous maps is continuous.

Comment: @Gustave: So you need to show $A \mapsto e^A$ is continuous.  For marix $A$ or bounded operator $A$ it is clear.  But the OP does not spell out his/her assumptions.  Physicists talk about semigroups of unbounded operators, for example.

Comment: @GEdgar A semigroup by definition is continuous, we don't talk here about the $X(t)$ as operator but as one variable function. Cordially.